# Google Spreadsheet clearContent() function error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone tell me why this function isn't working?  Produces error "Cannot find function clearContent() in object Sheet"

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row[1] == newData[j][1] && row[2] == newData[j][2] && row[3] == newData[j][3] && row[6] == newData[j][6] && row[7] == newData[j][7] && row[8] == newData[j][8]){        
      duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[4].length).setValues(newData);
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check the classes: [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) and [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

- [clearContents()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clearContents%28%29) is a method of [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).
- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearContent%28%29) is a method of [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).